# WooCommerce: CSS - Target specific product categories

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added dropshaddow to product images in catalouge-pages. But i want to leave the products of the category "utility" out, so the pictures in this category do **not** have drop shaddow. (EDIT: so they don't have dropshaddow even if they are shown in another category where they also belong) 
This is what I have to add to all products:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px #aaa !important;
}
```

I'm trying to target the specific category:

```
.product-cat-utility ul.products li.product a img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #aaa !important;
}
```

It does not work, and I am hoping for a more elegant solution. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<body class="...">` on each category page contain unique classes, both the term id and term name

Try something like this

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px #aaa !important;
}

.term-utility ul.products li.product a img, .myclass-utility ul.products li.product a img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #aaa !important;
}
```

add a custom body class for term (parent) utility and the childs

```php
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $term_slug = 'utility';
        $taxonomy  = 'product_cat';
        $term_id   = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id; // Get the term ID
        $child_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // Get the children terms IDs
        $terms_ids = array_merge( $child_ids, [$term_id] ); // an array of all term IDs (main term Id and it's children)

        if ( has_term( $terms_ids, $taxonomy, $post->ID ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'myclass-utility';
        }
    }

    return $classes;  
}
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching, this seams to do the trick:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px #aaa ;
}

.product_cat-utility img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px #aaa !important;
}
```